# "You are not your f***ing khakis" - What does "khakis" exactly mean in the Fight Club movie?

Tags: meaning, expressions, slang, cinema

> You are not the car you drive
>   You are not your fucking khakis!

I absolutely love Fight Club - this is a cult movie.

I know that *khakis* mean a special color used for army dresses; but I want to know what it means in the context of the movie. What did Tyler Durden mean by this?

What does *khakis* mean?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khaki

Comment: @JanDvorak, yes i know what khakis mean! it is special color used for army dresses; but i want to know what it means in the context of the movie! What did Tyler Durden mean by this?

Comment: the fact that Tyler's crew in the movie dressed up in khaki uniform - did he want to say 'it does not matter what you dress?'

Comment: Have you tried looking up the word exactly as it is? _Khakis_ is not the same as _khaki_ (adjectives do not have plural forms in English).

Comment: It actually has the potential of generating a good answer.  Adjectives can "become" nouns, for example we talk about "looking after the old". If we're feeling down and low in morale,  we're having [the blues](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/blues).

Comment: Trousers made from *jean fustian* fabric are now just called 'jeans'; trousers made from khaki fabric are now just called 'khakis'.

Comment: http://xkcd.com/922/

Comment: It's the final "refutation" in a stream of them... *"You are not your job... You're not how much money you have in the bank... not the car you drive... not the contents of your wallet... not your fucking khakis."* In which context it doesn't really matter exactly what ***khakis*** means to the speaker or the addressee. Obviously they're all supposed to be *visible symbols of wealth and success*, though personally I'd tend to see the wearing of khaki (trousers) as a *negative* trait if I had to place it somewhere on the "desirable/undesirable" scale.

Comment: RE: _@JanDvorak, yes i know what khakis mean! it is special color used for army dresses; but i want to know what it means in the context of the movie!_ You could have avoided that comment if you had just stated that in your question to begin with. Had you included a simple, "I understand it is a special color for army uniforms, but..." that would have helped everyone start at the same place. However, you asked instead: "What does _khakis_ mean?" so don't be surprised if the first response you get is a link telling you the meaning of _khakis_.

Comment: You broke the rules!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned what *khakis* actually means in some non-rhotic accents. Non-rhotic accents are ones in which the *r* sound is only pronounced when it's followed by a vowel (e.g. ***ri**ght*); the *r* is silent elsewhere. *Khakis* is a humorous pronunciation-spelling of **car keys** in some areas of the USA (such as Boston). The *r* is silent because it's followed by a consonant, so it's pronounced *KAH-KEEZ* which could alternatively be spelt *khakis*.

Here's an illustration from *A Historical Phonology of English* by Donka Minkova (p274):

> [image: khakis - car keys]

I assume it also means *car keys* in the quote in the OP:

> You are not the car you drive
> You are not your fucking khakis! [**car keys**]

Comment: Is the *-kis* of *khakis* **really** pronounced like *keys*? That's incredible.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: I wouldn't say the *-kis* is the same as *keys*, but that's what most sources say. In casual speech, most long vowels are reduced anyway.

Comment: haha lol, years later someone answered... i think this is he meant , cuz he says first "car you drive" then car keys..

Comment: Oh, well done! That does make sense now. Glad I didn't upvote any of the answers back in 2014.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: AmE doesn't have phonemic vowel length, so the last syllable of *khakis* (/-kiz/) resembles *keys* (/kiz/)

Answer (score 11):

"Khakis" is often used to refer to pants (that are khaki-colored, or made of the khaki textile). For example, Old Navy has a khakis page that lists [various pants](http://www.oldnavy.com/products/khakis.jsp) and one specific to men's [khakis](http://www.oldnavy.com/products/mens-khaki-pants.jsp).

In the context of the movie, khakis are another 'material good' that Tyler denounces, like cars, ikea furniture, etc.

Comment: Another example: http://www.gap.com/products/mens-khaki-pants.jsp

Comment: I agree with this answer, but would add that khaki pants have class overtones, as they are commonly seen in white-collar work environments in North America (as part of the ["business casual" dress style](http://www.career.vt.edu/JobSearchGuide/BusinessCasualAttire.html#ATTIREMENWOMEN)).

Comment: *Khakis* used to (at least) refer to military dress. [*A khaki uniform is often referred to as khakis.*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khaki) (Wikipedia) Members of different militaries sometimes had different kinds of uniforms, and *khakis* was one type.

Comment: very good now I see khakis is just another type of pants, another symbol of consumerism... any kind of clothes that everyone wants, desires....

Comment: lol actually khakis in this context means "car keys"

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I have a clue. Sir Terence Conran, a founder of Habitat, an advocate of design and minimalism, supposedly said, ***"I am not my khakis"***

Meaning:

> The stuff you own, wear, etc. does not define you. This is not about a higher status symbol. This is just about things / stuff in general. I suppose the minimalistic rhetoric of Fight Club refers to this sentense, because it is a symbol of not beeing addicted to material posessions.

Comment: Can you please add links to your sources? Once added, this answer will be a good one.

Answer (score 0):

The character Tyler Durden is referring to a popular commercial (late 1990's) from The Gap clothing company. It showed people dancing to swing music (a retro trend at the time) to promote their khakis pants. His line is mocking the vapid materialistic commercialism of the era. Which is sadly tame compared to now in 2021.